# How to intercept deserialisation with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

For example, I have JSON

```
{
  "url": "//n.ya.com"
}
```

In order to deserialize, I define the data class

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    @SerialName("url")
    val link: String,
)
```

After deserializing the `Foo` object has

`foo.link` with  `"//n.ya.com"`

How can I remove the `//` during the deserializing, which means `foo.link` with  `"n.ya.com"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [custom `Serializer`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) for a single property:

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    @SerialName("url")
    @Serializable(with = FooLinkDeserializer::class)
    val link: String,
)

object FooLinkSerializer : KSerializer<String> {
    override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Foo.link", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): String {
        return decoder.decodeString().substringAfter("//")
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: String) {
        encoder.encodeString("//$value")
    }
}
```

Or you can [intercept JSON transformations](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-transformations) using `JsonTransformingSerializer`:

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    @SerialName("url")
    @Serializable(with = FooLinkInterceptor::class)
    val link: String,
)

object FooLinkInterceptor : JsonTransformingSerializer<String>(String.serializer()) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return JsonPrimitive(element.jsonPrimitive.content.substringAfter("//"))
    }
}
```